# compute group automorphisms using magma

Tags: group-theory, automorphism-group, computer-algebra-systems, magma-cas

I'm learning how to use MAGMA to compute automorphism groups, and I have difficulty interpreting the output.  Concrete (and functional) example:

```
G := SL(2,3);
print "generators of SL(2,3):  ", Generators(G);
AG := AutomorphismGroup(G);
print "Aut( SL(2,3) ):   ", AG;
```

Output (executed via the online MAGMA calculator):

```
generators of SL(2,3):   {
    [1 1]
    [0 1],

    [0 1]
    [2 0]
}
Aut( SL(2,3) ):    A group of automorphisms of SL(2, GF(3))
Generators:
    Automorphism of SL(2, GF(3)) which maps:
        [1 1]
        [0 1] |--> [1 1]
        [0 1]
        [0 1]
        [2 0] |--> [1 2]
        [2 2]
    Automorphism of SL(2, GF(3)) which maps:
        [1 1]
        [0 1] |--> [0 1]
        [2 2]
        [0 1]
        [2 0] |--> [0 2]
        [1 0]
    Automorphism of SL(2, GF(3)) which maps:
        [1 1]
        [0 1] |--> [1 0]
        [2 1]
        [0 1]
        [2 0] |--> [0 1]
        [2 0]
    Automorphism of SL(2, GF(3)) which maps:
        [1 1]
        [0 1] |--> [1 1]
        [0 1]
        [0 1]
        [2 0] |--> [0 1]
        [2 0]
    Automorphism of SL(2, GF(3)) which maps:
        [1 1]
        [0 1] |--> [1 2]
        [0 1]
        [0 1]
        [2 0] |--> [2 1]
        [1 1]
```

So $SL(2,3)$ has two generators, the matrices $A := \begin{bmatrix}1&1 \\\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ and $B := \begin{bmatrix}0  &1 \\\ 2 & 0\end{bmatrix}$, and MAGMA says that $Aut(SL(2,3))$ is generated by four automorphisms $f_1, \ldots, f_4$  and specify how each $f_i$ acts on $A$ and $B$.  What I don't understand about the MAGMA output:

1. Take for instance $f_1$.  What do the $[0, 1]$ and $[2,2]$ mean under $A$ and $B$, respectively?
2. Take again $f_1$.  What does $f_1(A) \mapsto [1,1]$ mean?  (e.g. $AB$?)
3. I know that MAGMA uses right group action.  Does this convention extend to group automorphisms as well?  In order words, does $f_i(xy) = f_i(x) f_i(y)$ or $f_i(y) f_i(x)$?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Follow up question:  I just realize that the output of MAGMA's $AutomorphisGroup$ command is a 'GrpAuto'.  How can I convert it back to a "regular group"?  Thanks!

Comment: You can map a GrpAuto to an isomorphic GrpPerm using $\mathtt{PermutationRepresentation}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer 1. and 2. together: I think there's just a whitespace error, i.e.

```
Generators:
    Automorphism of SL(2, GF(3)) which maps:
        [1 1]
        [0 1] |--> [1 1]
        [0 1]
        [0 1]
        [2 0] |--> [1 2]
        [2 2]
```

should be

```
Generators:
    Automorphism of SL(2, GF(3)) which maps:
        [1 1]
        [0 1] |--> [1 1]
                   [0 1]
        [0 1]
        [2 0] |--> [1 2]
                   [2 2]
```

As for 3, I don't think $f_i(xy) = f_i(y)f_i(x)$ makes much sense? Take $f_i = \operatorname{id}_G$ for any non-abelian group $G$...

Comment: Thanks, and good point about $f_i(xy)$!